# How to navigate to an item in the list with c# webdriver?

Tags: c#, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to navigate to every link in the list that is found and I want to filter some href with css selector, like take all href elements, but do not include href with "logoff" and with "client" in it.

```cs
 int linkCount = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")).Count;  
 for (int i = 0; i <= linkCount - 1; i++)
 {
     List<IWebElement> linksToClick = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a[href]")).ToList();
     driver.Navigate().........
 }
```

Comment: Provide some html source for reference

Comment: http://localhost:54598/Client/Details/Contracts/1
http://localhost:54598/User/LogOff
I want test not to log off from the page by clicking this link and skip all contracts from opening

Comment: Improved code formatting and added C# highlighting.

Comment: This is going to be a pain because you are going to get a collection of links, click on a link that takes you off the page, and then go back to the original page where all the links in your collection will be stale. You should look into foreach loops. They are an easier way to do loops like this. `ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")); foreach (IWebElement link in links) { // do stuff }`